# Number of primitive elements for $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$ if $1\neq m\mid n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, splitting-field, galois-extensions

The number of primitive elements for $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ is given by the following formula:$$(p-1)\cdot\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\cdot p^{\tfrac{n}{d}},$$ where 'the primitive element for $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$' means 'an element $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}=\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$', and $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

My question is that 'what is the total number of elements in the following set:$$\left\{\beta\in\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}\,:\,\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}=K(\beta)\right\}$$ if $K=\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$ with $1\neq m\mid n$?'

Please, give some comments or any references. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a general result. The number of primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)q^{n/d},$$
since the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)q^{n/d}.$$
Therefore, the number of primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ is
$$\sum_{d\mid (n/m)}\mu(d)p^{n/d}.$$

Comment: FranzNietzsche, you mean the 'primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$' as the root of primitive polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. In my question, the 'primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$' as the root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. My question is the number of elements $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}=\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}(\alpha)$, where $m\mid n$.

Comment: @Primavera No, I mean 'irreducible' polynomials. I think your foumula above is wrong. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial)

Comment: FranzNietzsche, The second formula you mentioned above implies that the number of **monic & non-monic** irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is indeed $\frac{q-1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)q^{n/d}$. So, the first formula you mentioned above needs to be fixed as $(q-1)\cdot\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)q^{n/d}$. Or, what am I missing?

Comment: We only count monic polynomials, because no matter what the leading coefficient is, the roots are the same. For example, you can choose $p=3$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Ah, now I know what I was thinking wrong. Thanks for the kind comments.